# Updating database without grabbing all the rows

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Currently I do a property to property comparison with reflection to determine which values I should update in the database. The problem is that before I can do the comparison of the existing and new value, I need to grab all the rows from the database. These rows are already filtered but can contain thousands of records. As a result, my program is extremely slow and is bottlenecked by all the SELECT LINQ to SQL queries. These select queries take minutes at a time for each to complete.

Example LINQ:

```
    List<Customer> customersFromDatabase= _customerRepository
        .List()
        .Where(c=> c.country.Equals(country))
        .ToList();
```

This is the LINQ I use to determine whether they are a new customer or if they exist in which case they would be updated.

```
var customerInDb = customersFromDatabase
        .Where(c=> c.id.ToLower() == customer.id.ToLower())
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way to filter and grab only specific rows without having to pull the entire dataset down first?

The source data is a CSV file and the target is a database table\

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just grab the Id's from the initial query, that way you would be searching an indexed column (i hope) and would be much quicker?

Comment: What is changing the values that need to be checked? If it's the app then your app should already know just the ones need to be changed. If it's something else then you're probably doing this the wrong way. A select query from a filtered table should not be taking minutes unless there a lot of rows (10's of millions) or there are missing indexes (or both).

Comment: @Hexie The id column is a bit misleading as it isn't actually the key in the table. I can't grab the id at the beginning because the customer id's are only unique to each country. They might overlap across countries.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I am pulling the data from a csv file so I will only know if the value is different when I do the comparison. I am not sure why it takes so long but when I look at the console output It hangs on the select statements

Comment: So really what you're doing is trying to merge a CSV file into a database? Are you interested in pursuing any alternative methods? I'm going to add this info to the question. Please edit it if it's incorrect

Comment: This is about the slowest way possible to do this. The quickest way is to import the CSV into a staging table and run a single update statement

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, that is correct. Each time the database is updated it will be based on the CSV. I'm willing to try anything if it boosts the performance. If I do the staging table approach will I be able to get the granularity of tracking which specific rows/columns/values have been modified?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid By a staging table do you mean just having a temporary table with all the new values then just doing a cross comparison between the old table and the temporary one?

Comment: Yes but a staging table isn't temporary. It lives in your database. Then you can for example do an update query to mark all the records in your staging table that are different to the target table. That tracks modified records if you wan to know that. Then you can do another update that applies the changed records in staging to the target table. So you basically need to be able to create a table and you need to be able to import your entire CSV into it. I don't know what record count we're talking here but for 100,000 rows I would expect the import and update process to take less than a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application side you should be tracking your dirty rows (Ids) and their respective version information. (Row Version # / Last Modified Date/Time) For example if you are displaying a list of editable rows, your application should at a minimum be responsible for tracking which rows have been modified, from there you would retrieve your Customers by ID, validate that their Version information is the same, (someone else hasn't modified the record while your current user was editing) handle the merge, overwrite, or notification if there was a concurrent edit, and then update the source entity based on your property inspection.

So for example if you have 50 rows displayed, as a user edits a row, it gets added to a "dirty" collection. When you go to save the changes, you load Customers /w

given: dirtyCustomerIds = List containing the dirty rows...

```
dbContext.Customers.Where(c=> dirtyCustomerIds.Contains(c=>c.CustomerId));
```

and work with your entities against your dirty collection of Customer data from there.

Comment: I am pulling the data from a csv file so I will only know if the value is different when I do the comparison.Currently, I save all the customers that are different in a list and bulk update at the end.

Comment: So would the CSV only contain modified records? If that were the case I'd look at loading all or batches of rows from the CSV into an in-memory list of objects. Provided the CSV file contains IDs, then using the IDs from the CSV contents as the "dirtyCustomerIds" from my previous example.
I.e. var dirtyCustomerIds = csvItems.Select(x => x.CustomerId).ToList();

Comment: Note that would only be if the # of records in the CSV was kept low. (<20) For larger sets it would be better to insert those records into a staging table (historical or purge after completion) where they can be joined to the permanent table by Customer ID. (Faster than large IN clauses) The staging table also gives you a recorded history of inserted changes.

Comment: The CSV contains all the information. It is up to the program to determine whether they are modified or not then I would update the database accordingly. The number of records in the CSV is tens of thousands.

Comment: Then the approach I would consider would be to import the CSV into a staging table /w a schema similar to the 'real' table. I'd put a ImportedDate /w default of current date/Time, Processed DateTime? on it, along with a flag/status for the processing result.  When processing the CSV it would insert into this table with no ProcessedDate or status, then after loaded, load a sub-set of records (say 100 at a time) joining from the staging entity back to the real table. The code can then compare, and if it finds a delta, transfer the data and update the processed date & status.

Comment: Joins with a staging table gives you historical audit history of your imports and lets you process these changes in the background and with tune-able bounds in terms of the # of rows being loaded from the real table at any given time. Failed imports can be recorded, and if needed, corrected and re-run through the import process without re-doing the whole file or messing around with clipping lines out of CSVs.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the Id, could you not just grab the row in the initial step of your process:

Something like:

```
List<Customer> customersFromDatabase= _customerRepository
.List()
.Where(c=> c.id == customer.id)
.ToList();
```

This would give you the list of clients found with the Id you provided, speeding the entire process up substantially?

Also, I'm assuming your Id column is indexed?